@Id vs @MapsId in JDL
Here is a JDL
entity Address {
  street String
  city String
  state String
  zipCode String
}

entity Contact {
    email String
    phone String
}

relationship OneToOne {
    Address{user(login)} to @Id @OnDelete("CASCADE") User with builtInEntity
    Contact{user(login)} to @MapsId @OnDelete("CASCADE") User with builtInEntity  
}

The annotation @MapsId adds the following line
addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="user_id" 

into the constraint of the contact DB table, which means that the value of the user_id volume (not null) has to be one of the id volume of the user table.  It doesn't do anything special in terms of ID mapping in the Java code. The ID attribute is still a generated value. A Contract entity instance can exit without its parent, the User.
The annotation @Id has a non-generated value Id attribute and mapping set up correctly in the @MapsId usage of the JPA/Hibernate.
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {
    @Id
    private Long id; // No @GeneratedValue here

    // Other address properties...

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId // Indicates that the ID of this entity is the same as the associated User's ID
    private User user;

    // Getters and setters...
}

In the Address entity, notice that we removed the @GeneratedValue annotation for the id field. Instead, we use @MapsId to indicate that the id of the Address entity should be the same as the associated User’s ID.
This way, the primary key of the Address entity is derived from the User entity, creating a shared primary key relationship. An address entity instance can't exit without its parent, the User.
The annotation @MapsId in a JDL leads to a different outcome as what it shall be in JPA/Hibernate. The annotation usage confuses people. Is my understanding the JPA annotation usage correct?
Also, how to get ride of
ignoring 'Contact' definitions as it is using a built-in Entity 'user': 'otherEntityRelationshipName' is set with value 'undefined' at relationship 'user' but no back-reference was found

?
